# How can I fetch videos in Django from my media folder?

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api

I want to render my videos and images using a dinamic JS. For that purpose I've done these codes:

```js
const fetchMediaFiles = async() => {
        
        
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp/get_media_files');
       
    const files = await  response.json();
        
    const content = document.getElementById('content');

            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                content.innerHTML =
                    `
                <div class="video-active">
                        
                        <video src= "media/${files[i]}' " controls>
                            Your browser does not support video tag.
                        </video>
                </div>
                `;
            }
        
        
       
        /* .catch(error => console.log(error)); */
        console.log(files);
    }
```

A HTML with well basically a section, this function in views.py

```
`def get_media_files(request): 
media_folder = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
files = []
for filename in os.listdir(media_folder):
    files.append(filename) 

return JsonResponse(files ,safe=False)`
```

and this code in urls.py:

```
 path('get_media_files/', get_media_files, name="get_media_files"),
```

The error I get is 404 and it shows me all the paths from Urls.py which of course doesn't match with my video src. I'd like to know how can I connect those videos or make the folder accesible so I can just use a relative path or something to get that.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

**Have you added this**

```
urls.py
--------

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

settings.py
---------
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Hi Nirmal, in my settings I've got : MEDIA_URL = 'djangoPages/myApp/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR/ 'myApp', 'media'). The media root is there since, my root is on the django project and this is just an app. So it works (I've tested with that console.log on the js function). But i got an error in urls.py. Do i have to import other thing? like "from django.conf import static" ?

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work either.

Comment: You said errors in project url or app url.If it in project url then yes you also have to import from django.conf import settings and 
from django.conf.urls.static import static because in urls.py you are pointing MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT inside settings module.